# is it true that for every real number x there is a sequence of rationals (of the form m/2^n) that converges to x ??

Tags: sequences-and-series, rational-numbers

Is it true that for every real number $x$ there is a sequence of rationals **of the form ($m/2^n$)** that converges to $x$ ?

where ($m/2^n$) is in base 10 ,  $m,n\in N$ .

Comment: What do you think? What have you tried?

Comment: Is it true that for every real number $x$ there is a sequence of rationals **of the form ($m/10^n$)** that converges to $x$ ?? Now, convert to base 2.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/users/418148/b-mehta 
https://math.stackexchange.com/users/446262/jos%c3%a9-carlos-santos                   https://math.stackexchange.com/users/99914/john-ma https://math.stackexchange.com/users/148155/leucippus             Thank you the question is answered

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HINT: For every $n$ there exists $m$ such that $x\in\left[\frac{m}{2^n},\frac{m+1}{2^n}\right)$.